# Collectionview App crashes when changing the scroll direction from vertical to horizontal

Tags: ios, swift5, collectionview

[image][image][image]I have a collectionview image app. The app works fine when the scrolling is done vertically, but when I change the scroll direction from vertical to horizontal the app crashes. Anybody had the same experience?

Error Message :

he behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-05-12 23:24:05.946779+0530 MasterBooster[8094:469647] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2020-05-12 23:24:05.947507+0530 MasterBooster[8094:469647] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: ; dataSource: >.
2020-05-12 23:24:05.947675+0530 MasterBooster[8094:469647] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
(lldb)

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: Sure. I have updated the storyboard with Attribute and Size inspector